# Why the pointer to function gets value 0x00000000?

Tags: function, pointers, nullpointerexception, visual-c++-6

[image]

Why proc which is a function pointer gets null value?

[image]
[image]
[image]

EDITED:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

My guess would be that the library you loaded doesn't export a function called "StartHook".

If the library is written in C++, which it looks like it is, the function name will be mangled based on its argument types (e.g, to something like `_Z9StartHookv`). Wrap the definition in `extern "C" { ... }` to prevent this.

Comment: But How to prove it does not export the function?

Comment: @duskwuff Do you mean what after EDITED?

Answer (score 0):

NULL is the documented return value for when the function fails. To get the reason, call [GetLastError](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679360%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and look it up [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681381%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).